# implicit intent to take square photos

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-camera

Is there a way to specify an implicit intent for square photos?

The following made no difference

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
takePictureIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
takePictureIntent.putExtra("scale", true);//on and off
```

I am testing with a Samsung Note 5. Is there a way to make this work on the Note 5? I am not yet rolling out my own camera.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such extras for known camera apps. These can be used for cropping intent after the picture is received from camera.